# How to tell my RPA(Blue Prism) that this macro(MS Excel) is done and proceed further for another macro?

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

How to tell RPA(Blue Prism) that this macro (MS Excel) is done and proceed further towards another macro?

Macro deals with 76000 rows and returns output in 5-10 minutes (depending upon connection)

bottom left panel, which shows the status keeps on refreshing progress percentage of macros . Which means it shows progress every block in that macro.

Comment: Why not just let Blue Prism execute the macro using `MS Excel VBO`'s `Run Macro` action, which will block processing until the macro's execution has concluded?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need run - macro from the ms excel vbo.  This executes any macro by name in target workbook. Your question is a little misleading though is this exactly what you wanted to do? If you're running a macro and waiting 5 minutes or so are you looking to execute the macro and then move on without waiting those 5 minutes? Afraid that bit is not possible without reprogramming the ms excel vbo to execute things asynchronously and even then I wouldn't recommend because you need to know when a VBO was completed or not which running async does not intuitively  allow you to do.

So to run macro use the VBO ms excel vbo run macro action, this automatically waits for a macros conclusion before moving on from the current stage